# Titanium TableView Row Seperatly Background

Tags: javascript, titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy, titanium-android

i get 5 categories data in my wordpress blog and listing titanium mobile app i added  row background on my rows but all rows same background how can seperatly background all rows ?

Here My Normal Table View Screen
http://i.hizliresim.com/EqR4l8.png

Here MY Added row.backgroundImage Screen
http://i.hizliresim.com/VLM12r.png

My Categories .JS

```
$.init = function() {

var rows = [];  
getCategories(function(_data) {

for (var x = 0; x < _data.length; x++) {

    rows.push(Alloy.createController('category-item', {
        data : _data[x]
    }).getView());

}

$.categories_table.setData(rows);

APP.Loading.hide();
});
```

Here my categries-items.js

```
$.c_title.text = args.data.name  ; 
$.c_counts.text = args.data.count  ; 
$.row.Item = args.data;
$.row.backgroundImage = 'durum.png';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use
`$.row.backgroundImage = args.data.bgImg;`

and add bgImg to your data object (where you set *name* and *count*).

Answer (score 0):

The same way you're passing args.anyParam you want.

So basically :

```
$.row.backgroundImage = args.data.bckImg; // which is different for each data obj you pass to your controller
```

Comment: i'm newbie i javascript how to can passing bckImg ?

Comment: In your _data array, each object has param called 'name' (just as count etc;) since it's being passed to the controller. Similarly, add a new param called 'bckImg' and give it a value of the image.png.